# VSTO OneClick Deplyoment - Missing Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to create a small Setup for an Outlook addin, which contains a reference to some TFS assemblies.

I tried to create a manual Setup via installshield, but this failed horribly, since the Outlook kept ignoring the Addin.

So the right way would be via 'Publish' and ClickOnce deplyoment. This would work, but there seems to be an indirect reference to Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll'. When I publish the AddIn, this Assembly does not get deployed and the vsto file can't install the AddIn properly.

So, I thought the easiest way would be to add the Assembly as well, but as as soon as I try to add the assembly via "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll", I get the error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll' 
could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and 
that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

My second approach was to create an own publishing profile and try to add this assembly manually, but it seems like profiles can be created only for web projects and not for addins.

I didn't really find much about this matter, via msdn I [get the following suggestion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/1f80e7a7-b877-43e9-bab6-432c8312a5d4/visual-studio-2012-outlook-addin-publish-microsoftwitdatastoredlldeploy-did-not-succeed?forum=outlookdev), which does not help at all.

Is there a solution for this problem I didn't think of?

Edit: I tried jessehouwing's suggestion. It's quite interesting: If I add the Assembly to the Main-Project (the interface to the Outlook) as Content and even set 'Do not copy' , I get the desired Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll.deploy - File,
but also the following error at unpacking:

> System.IO.IOException: The file
>   'C:\Users\matthias.mueller\AppData\Local
>   \Temp\Deployment\JVX5J0LT.O0R\8P6ZQORW.DQJ\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll'
>   already exists.

If I add the assembly to the project, which might need it directly (DataAccess to TFS), the file does not get created and I get the original error.
I tried "Copy if newer" and "Copy always" as well, but I get the 'already exists' error as well.

Comment: The WitDataStore is actually a Unmanaged C++ dll, so it can't be added as a project reference. try adding it as Content and set the build action to Copy when Newer. Though, officially you're not allowed to redistribute the TFS Object Model assemblies, you're officially required to point your users to the installer which can be found here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6

Answer (score 1):

For those who will be working on .Net core project and come into this problem. What I needed to do was adding those dlls into Project. And add it into project.json

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": { "includeFiles": [ "Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll", "Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll" ] }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "includeFiles": [ "Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll", "Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll" ]
  },
```

Otherwise, Visual studio will not copy those into output folder when you publish to Azure.

Comment: Hm thanks, might in fact come handy for me, when we switch to .net Core